# How to map or sort values of two different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sorting

I have a simple dataframe1 with 32 raws like this :

|  | tot |
| --- | --- |
| time | 67 |
| price | 44 |
| money | 35 |
| quality | 10 |

and i have another dataframe2 like this:

|  | france | UK | italy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| price | 33 | 67 | 87 |
| time | 42 | 57 | 98 |
| quality | 38 | 24 | 12 |
| money | 14 | 63 | 22 |

I would like to sort the values in my dataframe2 by the list in dataframe1, so
time,price,money,quality.

I can do it manually setting and index for dataframe2, but there are a lots of columns, i would like to do this in automatic way.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the output?

Comment: `df2.reindex(df1.index)` ?  I think time, price, quality, and money are in the index of both dataframes right?

Comment: Alternatively, `df2.loc[df1.index.to_list()]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still can `sort_index` just need pass the function with `key`

```
out = df2.sort_index(key=lambda x : df1.index.get_indexer(x))
Out[76]: 
         france  UK  italy
time         42  57     98
price        33  67     87
money        14  63     22
quality      38  24     12
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC and the structure of both dataframes is that time, price, quality, and money are in the index of both dataframes. Use,

```
df2.reindex(df.index)
```

*Note*: using the `reindex` method over `loc` because if for some reason, df1.index has value not in df2.index, `reindex` will return NaN were `loc` will give a KeyError.